# Issue Iterating MongoDB Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I just can't figure out what's wrong with this. Does anyone know why I get this error? I'm using Node, Express, MongoDB with Mongoose.

Here's the code, the `console.log()` lines are just to debug and they are what throw the error.

```
// report view
app.get("/report", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(foundUser);
        } else {
            console.log(foundUser);
            console.log();
            console.log(foundUser.purchases[0].phrase);
            res.render("report.ejs", {user:foundUser});
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the `user` document in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d4dc48fba3ef12437bf4b1"),
    "salt" : "30dd9c9942...",
    "hash" : "8c8c96d88a708...",
    "username" : "Christian Lewis",
    "email" : "email@email.com",
    "signupDate" : ISODate("2017-10-04T13:04:08.167Z"),
    "__v" : 6,
    "purchases" : [
        {
            "phrase" : "Porche 918 Spyder",
            "location" : "South Yarra"
        },
        {
            "phrase" : "Blinds",
            "location" : "United Kingdom"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's everything that comes out of the console:

```
{ _id: 59d4dc48fba3ef12437bf4b1,
  username: 'Christian Lewis',
  email: 'christianllewis@gmail.com',
  __v: 6,
  signupDate: 2017-10-04T13:04:08.167Z,
  purchases:
   [ { location: 'South Yarra', phrase: 'Porche 918 Spyder' },
     { location: 'United Kingdom', phrase: 'Blinds' } ] }

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'phrase' of undefined
    at /Volumes/Store/Lickety-Split/website/app.js:58:47
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Store/Lickety-Split/website/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3841:16)
    at /Volumes/Store/Lickety-Split/website/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /Volumes/Store/Lickety-Split/website/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

I can't find an answer to this, I can't spot the error, so I apologise if this is a duplicate question. And thank you for any help.

Comment: The typical reason is that your defined schema does not match the document structure. You should really fix the schema ( which is missing from the question ), but at a pinch, adding `.lean()` ie. `User.findById(req.user._id).lean().exec(function(err, foundUser) {..` should give you an immediate workaround. Show the schema if you need the correction explained.

Comment: You seem to have been correct Neil. I rewrote that section of the schema and it's working now. Thanks very much. And thank you for that tip on `.lean()`.

Comment: It's really about your schema. The problem is that `purchases` as defined in your schema does not match the same shape as the data you have stored. You can alternately use methods like `founduser.get('purchases')` for things that are not defined correctly and don't have default assigned accessors due to the mismatch in "shape" but that does not really help in "templates". So you either use `.lean()` or other methods to convert the stored data to a "raw" JavaScript object, or simply fix the schema.

Comment: Yep, I can now confirm you are correct, I accidentally got rid of the square brackets to for the `purchases` field in the schema definition. So I guess it wasn't prepared to search an array index on the line `console.log(foundUser.purchases[0].phrase);`. You have very impressive knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening on this line

```
console.log(foundUser.purchases[0].phrase);
```

This would suggest `foundUser.purchases` array is empty, however based on your data logged, it is not.

Can you confirm that that the data posted is in fact the correct log information.

Comment: I can confirm for sure that the data I've shown is the data being targeted. I just got it working. Neil Lunn's comment  seems to have been correct. I'm still not sure exactly what the problem was, but his comment inspired me rewrite that part of the schema and it's working now. Thanks for your suggestion though, much appreciated.